# Comparing a numeric Python's list against a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dictionary

I have a Pandas's dataframe with 9 columns (called just dataframe), 5 of them called: [['DEG1','DEG2','DEG3','DEG4','DEG5']], it has almost 2000 rows. I have a list from which I build another dataframe with 5 columns called [['deg1','deg2','deg3','deg4','deg5']], this dataframe only has 1 row with the data series that needs to be checked in the other dataframe.

I need to check if the entire series (the 5 columns) from the little dataframe (n_serie_df), if repeated in the big dataframe, here my actual state, which gives me:

> "ValueError: Item wrong length 1 instead of 1709.".

This is my actual code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def check_repeated_deg(n_serie_list, dataframe):
    n_serie_dict = {
        "DEG1": [n_serie_list[0]],
        "DEG2": [n_serie_list[1]],
        "DEG3": [n_serie_list[2]],
        "DEG4": [n_serie_list[3]],
        "DEG5": [n_serie_list[4]],
    }

    n_serie_df = pd.DataFrame(n_serie_dict)

    repeated = dataframe[np.all(n_serie_df.values == n_serie_df.values, 1)].any().any()

    if repeated:
        return f"This deg serie is already measured"
    else:
        return None


dataframe = pd.read_csv(r"data_deg.csv")
n_serie_list = [2, 11, 21, 27, 41]

result = check_repeated_deg(n_serie_list, dataframe)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#create sample data - for test rewrite last row by n_serie_list values
np.random.seed(56)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,9)),
                          columns=['DEG1','DEG2','DEG3','DEG4','DEG5','a','b','c','d'])

n_serie_list = [2, 11, 21, 27, 41]

dataframe.iloc[-1, :5] = n_serie_list
print (dataframe)
   DEG1  DEG2  DEG3  DEG4  DEG5  a  b  c  d
0     5     4     0     2     9  7  6  4  9
1     7     1     8     2     0  5  6  1  9
2     5     5     2     9     3  5  9  2  1
3     0     4     6     2     0  8  6  4  0
4     2    11    21    27    41  2  1  3  8
```

Compare filtered rows  of `DataFrame` by list `n_serie_list` with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and test at least one match by [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
cols = ['DEG1','DEG2','DEG3','DEG4','DEG5']
repeated = (dataframe[cols].values == n_serie_list).all(axis=1).any()
print (repeated)
True
```

How it working:

```
print ((dataframe[cols].values == n_serie_list))
[[False False False False False]
 [False False False False False]
 [False False False False False]
 [False False False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution help us better than the @gtomer's solution (which works too), since there are times when is not only 5 columns of series to check, so when the time comes your solution is pretty easy to adjust. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

The below code appends the series to the dataframe and then leave only duplicated rows:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'DEG1': [1,2], 'DEG2': [3,4]})
df1.loc[len(df1)] = [1,3]
df1[df1.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

Comment: Thank you my friend! As I said your solution works perfect, but I know that sometimes we need to check more or less columns (longer series of data), for this variable case scenario the solution from @jezrael suits better to do some mods in the future as needed. Thanks for your time, have a nice day!